# Mysql: Time + int

Tags: mysql, time, addition

i have a table with a time field and i need to add an int field to it.
here's the line of code (it's a piece of a trigger.)

```
DECLARE duration Int;
[....]
SET NEW.appointmentEnd = NEW.appointmentTime + duration;
```

This works until the time gets to a full hour. So 8:30:00 + 1500 = 8:45:00 But 8:30:00 + 3000 = 0:00:00.

How to fix this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a "plain" int, you should be adding anexplicit *interval*:

```
new.appointmenttime = (new.appointmenttime + INTERVAL durationInMinutes MINUTE)
```

You are not limited to using `MINUTE`, of course: you can use `SECOND` if you need more precision.

Comment: thanks for your response, but
    SET NEW.appointmentEnd = NEW.appointmentTime + INTERVAL duration SECOND; doesn't work

Comment: @schoen [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89c97/2) is a link. I'm a bit rusty on mysql - you need parentheses around the expression. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't do direct date/time math by adding what you are trying of "seconds".  But you can do via Date_Add() and Date_Sub() such as

set appointmentEnd = date_Add( appointmentTime, interval 15 minutes )

Comment: thanks for the respons but  SET NEW.appointmentEnd=Date_add(NEW.appointmentTime, INTERVAL duration MINUTE); doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use date arithmetic, like:

```
    mysql> SELECT '2008-12-31 23:59:59' + INTERVAL 1 SECOND;
    -> '2009-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Or

```
    mysql> SELECT DATE_ADD('2010-12-31 23:59:59', INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    -> '2011-01-01 23:59:59'
```

So if duration is, for example, in seconds:

```
    SET NEW.appointmentEnd = NEW.appointmentTime + INTERVAL duration SECOND;
```